# Q: is there a way to ignore blanks cells in a csv file but still graph the data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am doing a personal project for school using Python. I am just trying to clean and plot data from a csv file using matplotlib.pyplot and pandas. A problem I am running in to is for blank cells in the csv it reads it as a 0.

my previous attempts to fix this have been to remove all the blank cells in the csv but that (obviously) gives me an error because there isn't the same amount of points in the y-axis as there is in the x-axis.

Data:

## unix time

,1296086400,1297900800,1299542400,132753600,1330992000,1358985600,1360627200,1362441600,1390435200,1392076800,1393891200

Becker,18:20.6,17:53.1,18:06.2,18:00.3,17:51.2,18:05.0,18:05.3,18:14.9,,,
Casey,19:14.7,17:51.2,17:16.4,17:18.6,16:49.3,17:05.0,17:02.7,16:51.2,16:57.0,16:57.4,16:44.2
Frid,17:18.9,17:00.9,16:54.1,16:47.5,16:34.1,16:33.0,16:23.3,16:22.5,16:27.0,16:10.1,16:15.6
Lamb,18:09.6,17:50.7,17:39.9,,17:42.9,17:44.0,17:35.2,,,,
Noble,18:18.9,17:42.0,17:31.2,17:26.9,17:14.0,17:43.0,17:59.2,17:19.9,17:25.0,17:42.7,
Voorhees,,18:49.2,18:19.4,17:29.8,16:53.9,17:07.0,16:50.6,16:44.6,16:50.0,16:47.3,16:41.2

```
'''
first try at dealing with blank cells in the csv file 
doesnt work because the graph needs to have the same amount 
of plot points in the x as it does in the y. 
'''
with open('clean3.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    dates = cleanLine(header)
    user_list = []  # new list for inputs
    for row in reader:
        scores = []
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if (row[i] != '' ):
                try:
                    errorCheck = float(row[i][:2])  
       # checks if the value of row[i] can be converted to a float
                    scores.append(row[i])
                except:
                    user_list.append(row[i])
        user_list.append(dates)
        user_list.append(scores)
```

what I want is a graph that doesn't spike down to 0 with every blank cell. I am hoping to make it so the blank cell is either ignored (for the blanks in between two points) or just continues with the same slope(for when the blanks are at the end of a set of erg scores).

What I get with this code is the correct form that I want for my data in but the y-value list (the erg scores) is shorter than the x-value list (Unix time) so it won't work when plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.

If anyone has any tutorials or tips for using pandas or matplotlib (or other modules I should look in to) in order to better utilize my data that would be much appreciated. I am trying to learn as much as possible so preferably no answers.

Comment: If you use pandas `read_csv` method, blank cells are automatically converted to `nan` and when you plot these in `matplotlib`, they are visualized as gaps in the graph.  If you want the blanks visualization that you're seeking, using `read_csv` is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to loop over columns in the transposed DataFrame and plot them, dropping `NA`s:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter


df = pd.read_csv('scores.csv', index_col=0)
df = df.T
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

fmt = DateFormatter("%M:%S")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:' + df[c])
    df[c].dropna().plot(ax=ax, label=c, style='.-')

ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image: chart]

P.S. I've added another '0' to unix time '132753600' bringing it to 2012 from 1974 to make it more in line with other records

Comment: Difficult question... there is a course on Coursera covering matplotlib (https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-plotting) which I think is quite OK as an intro, and for more specific questions you'll probably end up on stackoverflow anyway ;)